# Usando Group By no SAS Guide

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, group-by

Estou tendo problemas na utilização do comando `GROUP BY`, no **SAS**. 
Por definição, o SAS só aceita o `GROUP BY` se for utilizado no `SELECT` uma função de sumarização. Até aí, ok. Rodando a *Proc* abaixo, o resultado sai corretamente:

```
proc sql;
    create table tabela_nova as
    select  nr_prpt_vcld,
            (max(ult_acl_atv)) as ult_acl_atv format ddmmyy10.
    from    tabela_base
    group by nr_prpt_vcld
    ;
quit;
```

nr_prpt_vcld    ult_acl_atv
23157           02/01/2014
27175           03/07/2014
29350           17/02/2014

Porém, acrescentando mais 2 campos ao `SELECT`, (conforme abaixo) a *Proc* retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
proc sql;
    create table tabela_nova as
    select  nr_prpt_vcld,
            nr_cvn_srvc,
            cd_cli_srvc,
            (max(ult_acl_atv)) as ult_acl_atv format ddmmyy10.
    from    tabela_base
    group by nr_prpt_vcld
    ;
quit;
```

nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv
    23157           140594        504217876  02/01/2014
    23157           147914        510003171  02/01/2014
    23157           153120        511284856  02/01/2014
    27175           140676        203940185  03/07/2014
    27175           141805        931007593  03/07/2014
    27175           150291        510955695  03/07/2014
    29350           137242        508122116  17/02/2014
    29350           145502        30139405   17/02/2014

Já tentei adicionar os campos novos ao `GROUP BY`, usar `HAVING`, mas nada resolveu. Ainda não consegui entender como funciona o `GROUP BY` no **SAS**. 
Alguém pode me ajudar?

O resultado esperado é o seguinte:

```
nr_prpt_vcld   nr_cvn_srvc       cd_cli_srvc ult_acl_atv 
    23157           153120        511284856  02/01/2014 
    27175           150291        510955695  03/07/2014 
    29350           137242        508122116  17/02/2014
```

Ou seja, os valores nr_cvn_srvc e cd_cli_srvc que estão na data mais recente (ult_acl_atv), agrupado pelo nr_prpt_vcld.

Comment: Parece que ele implicitamente adicionou os novos campos no `group by`, em vez de retornar um erro (o que, creio eu, seria o que uma consulta SQL num BD normal faria). A propósito, esse foi o resultado obtido, certo? Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Sugestão: edite sua pergunta acrescentando os detalhes relevantes, não tente postar como comentário. Se estiver com dificuldade na formatação, selecione o texto e use o botão "Amostra de código" (que se parece com isto: **{ }**), e ele ficará formatado como código (em fundo cinza, com fonte monoespaçada).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - (Workaround) use subqueries:

```
select  t1.nr_prpt_vcld                               as nr_prpt_vcld,
        (select t2.nrcvn_srvc
             from tabela_base t2
             where t2.nr_prpt_vcld = t1.nr_prpt_vcld
             order by t2.ult_acl_atv desc
             limit 1
        )                                             as nrcvn_srvc,
        (select t2.cd_cli_srvc
             from tabela_base t2
             where t2.nr_prpt_vcld = t1.nr_prpt_vcld
             order by t2.ult_acl_atv desc
             limit 1
        )                                             as cd_cli_srvc,
        (max(t1.ult_acl_atv))                         as ult_acl_atv
    from    tabela_base t1
    group by t1.nr_prpt_vcld
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/584b0/1/0)

---

Tenho pouca familiaridade com o SAS, mas pelo que eu entendi, ele possui conformidade com os padrões SQL. Vou responder de forma mais didática, de modo que você consiga identificar onde pode estar errando e o que fazer para corrigir:

#### Visão geral sobre queries SQL

De forma abstrata, pode-se dizer que uma consulta executa os seguintes passos, nessa ordem:

1. Descobre a(s) tabela(s) a se consultar, fazendo as junções aplicáveis;

   Ex.: `from tabela_base`

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv foo
   23157           140594        504217876  30/12/2013   bar
   23157           147914        510003171  01/01/2014   bar
   23157           153120        511284856  02/01/2014   bar
   27175           140676        203940185  01/07/2014   bar
   27175           141805        931007593  02/07/2014   bar
   27175           150291        510955695  03/07/2014   bar
   29350           137242        508122116  16/02/2014   bar
   29350           145502        30139405   17/02/2014   bar
   99999           999999        999999999  18/02/2014   baz
   ```
2. Filtra as linhas retornadas, conforme a condição `where`;

   Ex.: `where foo = bar`

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv foo
   23157           140594        504217876  31/12/2013   bar
   23157           147914        510003171  01/01/2014   bar
   23157           153120        511284856  02/01/2014   bar
   27175           140676        203940185  01/07/2014   bar
   27175           141805        931007593  02/07/2014   bar
   27175           150291        510955695  03/07/2014   bar
   29350           137242        508122116  16/02/2014   bar
   29350           145502        30139405   17/02/2014   bar
   -----           ------        --------   ----------   baz (X)
   ```
3. Agrupa conforme o critério da cláusula `group by`;

   Ex.: `group by no_prpt_vcld`

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv foo  tupla de agrupamento

   23157           140594        504217876  31/12/2013   bar \
   23157           147914        510003171  01/01/2014   bar  (23157)
   23157           153120        511284856  02/01/2014   bar /

   27175           140676        203940185  01/07/2014   bar \
   27175           141805        931007593  02/07/2014   bar  (27175)
   27175           150291        510955695  03/07/2014   bar /

   29350           137242        508122116  16/02/2014   bar \(29350)
   29350           145502        30139405   17/02/2014   bar /
   ```
4. "Achata" os grupos, transformando cada um em uma linha só, acrescentando colunas de acordo com as funções de agregação

   Ex.: `(max(ult_acl_atv)) as ult_acl_atv`

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv foo
   23157          [Achatado]   [Achatado]    02/01/2014  [Achatado]
   27175          [Achatado]   [Achatado]    03/07/2014  [Achatado]
   29350          [Achatado]   [Achatado]    17/02/2014  [Achatado]
   ```
5. Filtra de novo, agora as linhas "achatadas" (e não as originais)

   Ex.: `having ult_acl_atv < '06/06/2014'` (sintaxe imprecisa)

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv foo
   23157          [Achatado]   [Achatado]    02/01/2014  [Achatado]
   -----          ----------   ----------    03/07/2014  ---------- (X)
   29350          [Achatado]   [Achatado]    17/02/2014  [Achatado]
   ```
6. Escolhe as colunas a retornar; só pode usar colunas agrupadas (i.e. que faziam parte do `group by` ou agregações de outras colunas (i.e. que tiveram algum valor definido após o "achatamento").

   Ex.: `select nr_prpt_vcld, (...) as ult_acl_atv`

   ```
   nr_prpt_vcld   ult_acl_atv
   23157          02/01/2014
   29350          17/02/2014
   ```

#### Como isso se aplica ao seu caso

Como você pode ver, não dá pra acrescentar as colunas `nrcvn_srvc` e `cd_cli_srvc` pois elas foram "achatadas" ao se pegar várias linhas da tabela e transformar em uma só. O máximo que você pode fazer, é agregar elas também, se for isso que você quer. Ex.:

```
select  nr_prpt_vcld,
        (min(nrcvn_srvc)) as nrcvn_srvc,
        (sum(cd_cli_srvc)) as cd_cli_srvc,
        (max(ult_acl_atv)) as ult_acl_atv format ddmmyy10.

    nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc   cd_cli_srvc   ult_acl_atv
    23157          140594       1525505903    02/01/2014
    29350          137242       538261521     17/02/2014
```

**Ou**, adicionar uma (ou mais) delas no grupo - mas fazendo isso, o agrupamento será diferente. Ex.:

```
group by nr_prpt_vcld, nrcvn_srvc

    nr_prpt_vcld   nrcvn_srvc     cd_cli_srvc ult_acl_atv  foo           tupla de agrupamento

    23157           140594        [Achatado]  31/12/2013   [Achatado] => (23157,140594)

    23157           147914        [Achatado]  01/01/2014   [Achatado] => (23157,147914)

    23157           153120        [Achatado]  02/01/2014   [Achatado] => (23157,153120)

    27175           140676        [Achatado]  01/07/2014   [Achatado] => (27175,140676)

    27175           141805        [Achatado]  02/07/2014   [Achatado] => (27175,141805)

    27175           150291        [Achatado]  03/07/2014   [Achatado] => (27175,150291)

    29350           137242        [Achatado]  16/02/2014   [Achatado] => (29350,137242)

    29350           145502        [Achatado]  17/02/2014   [Achatado] => (29350,145502)
```

Etc. Se você acrescenta outros campos na cláusula `group by`, ele vai agrupar pela [**tupla**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enupla) de campos - sendo que cada combinação diferente dos mesmos vai gerar um agrupamento, que posteriormente será achatado e poderá ter seus valores agregador.

Normalmente, uma consulta tal como a que você fez geraria um erro no SQL. Mas *aparentemente*, o que o SAS fez foi acrescentar implicitamente os demais campos na condição de agrupamento, de modo que sua consulta foi feita como se o `group by` estivesse assim:

```
group by nr_prpt_vcld, nrcvn_srvc, cd_cli_srvc
```

De modo que somente linhas que tivessem esses 3 valores **idênticos** é que fariam parte do mesmo agrupamento. Se não existe mais de uma linha com essas condições, o resultado é como se ele não tivesse agrupado nada, simplesmente retornado cada linha separadamente...

#### Workaround

Não sei se o que você quer fazer é possível dentro da própria cláusula `group by`: obter o valor de uma coluna correspondente ao máximo de **outra** coluna. Um *workaround* seria usar duas subqueries, uma para cada coluna; em cada uma delas, pega-se o valor da coluna correta correspondente ao valor máximo da data, para um código específico:

```
select t2.nrcvn_srvc
    from tabela_base t2
    where t2.nr_prpt_vcld = ### um código fixo ###
    order by t2.ult_acl_atv desc
    limit 1
```

Isso é feito na seção `select` - quando o agrupamento já foi feito e se está montando a linha com os resultados. Ordena-se as linhas de forma descrescente pela data (de modo que a primeira será a mais recente), e se limita a quantidade de resultados a `1`, de modo que só a maior delas será retornada. Pega-se o campo que você quer e usa-o como o valor da coluna:

```
select  t1.nr_prpt_vcld       as nr_prpt_vcld,
        (select ...)          as nrcvn_srvc,
        (select ...)          as cd_cli_srvc,
        (max(t1.ult_acl_atv)) as ult_acl_atv
```

Resultado final (note que dei um apelido para a tabela original):

```
select  t1.nr_prpt_vcld                               as nr_prpt_vcld,
        (select t2.nrcvn_srvc
             from tabela_base t2
             where t2.nr_prpt_vcld = t1.nr_prpt_vcld
             order by t2.ult_acl_atv desc
             limit 1
        )                                             as nrcvn_srvc,
        (select t2.cd_cli_srvc
             from tabela_base t2
             where t2.nr_prpt_vcld = t1.nr_prpt_vcld
             order by t2.ult_acl_atv desc
             limit 1
        )                                             as cd_cli_srvc,
        (max(t1.ult_acl_atv))                         as ult_acl_atv
    from    tabela_base t1
    group by t1.nr_prpt_vcld
```